# Gradient background on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I set some gradient color code on viewControllers that did not have an UICollecionView and it worked.  When I tried the gradient code on an UICollectionViewController, the gradient did not work.  Does anyone know how to add a gradient to an UICollectionView? (collectionView is inside a normal viewController)

Gradient code:

```
let topColor = UIColor(red: (191/255.0), green: (143/255.0), blue: (248/255.0), alpha: 1)
let bottomColor = UIColor(red: (131/255.0), green: (82/255.0), blue: (182/255.0), alpha: 1)

let gradientColors: [CGColor] = [topColor.CGColor, bottomColor.CGColor]
let gradientLoactions: [Float] = [0.0, 1.0]
let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
gradientLayer.locations = gradientLoactions
gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0)
```

Comment: Did you try to use self.collectionView instead of self.view ?

Comment: @Skylar Björn were you able to solve it?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I ended up dragging in an UIImage within an UImageView that I designed in sketch to have a gradient instead of coding in the gradient